# Flask pytest not initializing app

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask server that has `server.py` set up in the following way

**server.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(mybp)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config.foo = "bar"
```

**mybp.py**

```
@mybp.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def root():
    return app.config.foo
```

**test.py**

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    server.app.config['TESTING'] = True
    client = server.app.test_client()
    client
    yield client

def testbp(client):
    client.post('/mybp')
```

When I run the test, I get the following error

```
E       AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

because the configuration hasn't been initialized when running the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already initialising a config value 'TESTING' in your test file. So why not initialise your config for the test there as well

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    server.app.config.foo = "bar"
    server.app.config['TESTING'] = True
    client = server.app.test_client()
    client
    yield client

def testbp(client):
    client.post('/mybp')
```

Also you're posting to the endpoint `/mybp` but you're endpoint in `mybp.py` is for `/`